# \pageref and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, lastpage

Please can anyone tell me the source of the following error?

I simply entered

```
\label{xlastpage} on last page
```

and the call

```
\setkeys[KV]{fam}{lhead={Page \thepage of \pageref{xlastpage}}}
```

gave the following funny errors.

```
%%%%%%%%% Trace log %%%%%%%%%%

\T@pageref #1->\NR@setref {#1}\@secondoffive {#1}
#1<-xlastpage

\NR@setref #1->\begingroup \@safe@activestrue \expandafter \endgroup \expandaft
er \NR@@setref \csname r@#1\endcsname
#1<-xlastpage
{\begingroup}
{entering semi simple group (level 19) at line 141}

\@safe@activestrue ->\let \if@safe@actives \iftrue
{\let}
{changing \if@safe@actives=\iffalse}
{into \if@safe@actives=\iftrue}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\csname}
{\endgroup}
{restoring \if@safe@actives=\iffalse}
{leaving semi simple group (level 19) entered at line 141}

\NR@@setref #1->\ifx \@undefined #1\let #1\relax \fi \@setref #1
#1<-\r@xlastpage
{\ifx}
{false}

\@setref #1#2#3->\ifx #1\relax \protect \G@refundefinedtrue \nfss@text {\reset@
font \bfseries ??}\@latex@warning {Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space undef
ined}\else \expandafter \Hy@setref@link #1\@empty \@empty \@nil {#2}\fi
#1<-\r@xlastpage
#2<-\@secondoffive
#3<-xlastpage
{\ifx}
{false}
{\expandafter}

\r@xlastpage ->{2}{4}

\Hy@setref@link #1#2#3#4#5#6\@nil #7->\begingroup \toks 0={\hyper@@link {#5}{#4
}}\toks 1=\expandafter {#7{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}\edef \x {\endgroup \the \toks 0
 {\the \toks 1 }}\x
#1<-2
#2<-4
#3<-\@empty
#4<-\@empty
#5<-\@nil
! Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
<to be read again>
```

Comment: Please supply a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). We can't debug this without knowing what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @Lev: Are you *sure* you don't mean a minimal *failing* example?

Comment: @SamB: Minimal working example is [a](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html#x1-30002) [standard](http://techblog.ironfroggy.com/2007/02/minimal-working-examples-how-to-why-and.html) [term](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/627), where "working" means "working just enough to show the problem".

Comment: @Lev, @SamB — I've never understood where the ‘working’ term came from, myself. I just call them ‘minimal examples’ `;)`

Comment: More seriously, I've flagged this question because it's largely useless to keep around, considering it's all but been retracted as a question by its author in a comment below.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's causing your error; to even have a chance, I'd have to reproduce it, but I don't know what packages, etc., you're using.

But have you tried doing what you're doing by loading the [lastpage](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) package with `\pageref{LastPage}`?

Or alternatively, with `\total{page}` provided by the [totcount](http://ctan.org/pkg/totcount) package?

Or with `\ref{TotPages}` from the [totpages](http://ctan.org/pkg/totpages) package?

Comment: Problem solved: I had a look at how the hyperref package redefines \newlabel, and also at nameref and gettitlestring packages.

Comment: @Pluto: Great that you found it! In such cases it would also be great if you post it as answer instead of a comment, just for clarity. This helps readers finding your solution easier. You could even mark your own answer as accepted.